# how to use method to find two 'a' chars in a string in java?

Tags: java, methods, char

I am writing a method that goes through a string and returns true if exactly two 'a' characters are found. Obviously, not all conditions are being met, but I can't find how to fix it. The issue states that the boolean type has to be met. However, inside the loop, if a is not found in one iteration, nothing should happen. How do I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public static boolean hasTwoA(String s) {
        int aCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                aCounter++;
            } else if (aCounter == 2) {
                return true;
            } else if (i == s.length() - 1 && aCounter != 2) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: I hope you are calling hasTwoA() from your main()

Comment: I will be calling the method eventually @SRJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be neater to write it something like:

```
int aCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && aCounter <= 2; ++i) {
  if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') ++aCounter;
}
return aCounter == 2;
```

Comment: Your previous solution was actually better because the OP asked if there are (exactly) two 'a's not if there are *at least* two 'a's

Comment: the prev soln was better. you dont need two passes i guess.

Comment: @alfasin No - OP's current solution would return true for a string with two or more a's (if it compiled).

Comment: You write "no" and then write exactly what I did. Please read my comment again :)

Comment: @alfasin I am saying "no" to the "exactly two" bit in your comment, because it doesn't say that in the question.

Comment: I should have clarified, I meant exactly two. That was my bad.

Comment: @J.Doe'sverygoodfriend edited for that requirement. Please edit your question to add that.

Comment: You should remove the following condition from the for-loop: `&& aCounter <= 2` - you want to keep counting even if you've reached 2 ;)

Comment: @alfasin This stops execution once `aCounter == 3` - since the requirement is to return `true` if the string contains *exactly* 2 `a`s ("I should have clarified, I meant exactly two."), there is no need to count beyond there. But even if the requirement were *at least* 2 `a`s, there is no problem with that condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it using Regex, e.g:

```
String s = "dasfvasaako";
System.out.println(s.matches(".*a.*a.*"));
```

Comment: They're not necessarily together.

Comment: This solution will work only for two consecutive 'a's.

Comment: Though this solution is valid, using regex to count characters is not a recommended approach.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the requirement stated in the comments on my answer (where *exactly 2* is stated). You need `[^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean hasTwoA(String s) {
    if(s == null || s.length()==1)
      return false;

    int aCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == 'a')
            aCounter++;
        if (aCounter == 2)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```